# Why is my std::string.contains() not working?

Tags: c++, c++23

I am currently learning about reading and writing files in C++, I use Visual Studio Code, and I have my *c_cpp_properties.json* set: `"cppStandard": "c++23"`.

This program is about reading a file named *romeoandjuliet.txt* and the user types a word to see if it appears in the *.txt* file, counting the number of appearances.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    string find{};
    string word{};
    int word_counter{0};
    int matches{0};
    std::ifstream reader;

    reader.open("romeoandjuliet.txt");

    if (!reader)
    {
        cerr << "'romeoandjuliet.txt' wasn't found" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl
         << "Enter the substring to search for: ";
    cin >> find;

    while (reader >> word)
    {
        if (word.contains(find))
        {
            matches++;
        }
        word_counter++;
    }

    cout << word_counter << " words were searched..." << endl
         << "The substring " << find << " was found " << matches << " times" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if it is due to my IDE configuration, or compiler, or my code, but the error I got from compiler says: `'std::string' {aka 'class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} has no member named 'contains'`

SOLUTION: Manual compile worked, so I looked what was my VS Code C++ build version, solution was to add  `"-std=c++23"` in the `"args"`  section on the *tasks.json* file

Comment: What happens if you add `-std=c++23` as a compiler flag to your terminal and compile it manually?

Comment: What compiler / version are you using? Does it support `contains` yet?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` configures IntelliSense. It doesn't configure the compiler. You need to add `-std=c++23` to the compiler arguments.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply replace `if (word.contains(find))` with `if (word.find(find) != string::npos)`, which works in C++ versions prior to C++23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you use GCC as compiler. `std::string::contains` requires C++23 and at least GCC 11. Check [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) for feature support of compilers and standard libraries.

You can test which version of GCC is installed by:

```bash
g++ --version
```

To compile your file in C++23 mode you can use:

```bash
g++ -std=c++23 file.cpp
```

If you use CMake you can set:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
```

A full `CMakeLists.txt` example that works with any compiler is:

```
# set minimum CMake major and minor version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set your project name
project(Tutorial)

# force at least C++23 as standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

# create an executable from source files
add_executable(Tutorial file1.cpp file2.cpp)
```

Note that your compiler compiler may not have full support for C++23 yet. If you want to use specific features anyway, you can use the [feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) to ensure they are already supported. In case of `std::string::contains` you can use in your `file.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <string>

#ifndef __cpp_lib_string_contains
#error "The standard library doesn't support std::string::contains()."
#endif
```

If you compile this with GCC 11 and C++23 it works fine. If you use an older standard like C++20 you will get an error like:

```bash
user@pc:~$ c++ -std=c++20 file.cpp 
file.cpp:4:2: error: #error "The standard library doesn't support std::string::contains()."
    4 | #error "The standard library doesn't support std::string::contains()."
      |  ^~~~~
```

Comment: Hello, can you be more specific with the CMake solution? I do have CMake tools on my VS Code

Comment: @BrayanBarrera I have added a full CMake example. I would recommend calling CMake from the command line first to learn how to use it properly. This knowledge makes the later use of the IDE integration of CMake much easier.